# Sharepoint CacheManifestLink WebControl

Tags: 2013

Any ideas on what this control does?

Checked in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.cachemanifestlink%28v=office.15%29.aspx) , it has not mentioned what it does

Comment: Cachemanifest are in asp files that contains cached elements like ja or css.. Maybe it is The Same?